# Close In App Browser using Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview

I have this scenario.

1. The User opens a website inside a mobile game (in-app browser/web view)
2. The user clicks a button inside the website to close the browser and go back to the mobile game.

Is there any way that I achieve that using React/Javascript?

I checked other threads and window.close() doesn't work in webview

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need to communicate with the native app, using javascript callbacks, hrhttps://medium.com/blackmirror-media/callbacks-from-webview-to-javascript-sharing-data-between-native-code-and-html-bfc7251210af

because web view browser - is the part of native code of application and you don't have any possibilities to command over native app's browser.

Comment: any idea how can I achieve it? 

Comment: It's about using callbacks like <a href="callback:callbackName">Your link</a>. 
When user taps this specific link, your native app handling that it was a click on html-node with "callbackName" and closes browser. All you need to do is discuss with mobile devs to use this type callbacks and define callback name. I advice to use something like "close" :))) i'm not a mobile developer, but in our team we use this kind of connecting webview's pages and native browser.